# XCode 9.3 upgrade or replace libc++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, libc++

I have following code in C++ and it works perfectly fine on GCC, MSVC2015, Android NDK, ...

```
class JsonLongText {
private:
    enum JsonToken {
        JT_OBJECT,
        JT_ARRAY,
        JT_VARIABLE,
        JT_EMPTY
    };
    typedef std::vector<JsonToken> JsonTokenStack;
    JsonTokenStack                  m_OpenTokens;
....
    JsonLongText() : m_IgnoreEmptyItems(true), m_RequireItemSeparator(false), m_PrettyPrint(false) {}
}
```

I sucessfully compiled it on MacOS 10.13 from commandline with XCode 9.2 as well. But after my system was upgraded from 10.13 to 10.13.4 and Xcode to version 9.3. I'm facing following errors:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2141:9: error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of '__compressed_pair_elem<JsonLongText::JsonToken *, 0>'
      : _Base1(std::forward<_Tp>(__t)), _Base2() {}
        ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:423:7: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<JsonLongText::JsonToken *, std::__1::allocator<JsonLongText::JsonToken> >::__compressed_pair<long, true>'
      requested here
      __end_cap_(nullptr)
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:473:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<JsonLongText::JsonToken, std::__1::allocator<JsonLongText::JsonToken> >::__vector_base' requested here
    vector() _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_default_constructible<allocator_type>::value)
    ^
../Include/JsonLongText.h:162:2: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<JsonLongText::JsonToken,
      std::__1::allocator<JsonLongText::JsonToken> >::vector' requested here
        JsonLongText() : m_IgnoreEmptyItems(true), m_RequireItemSeparator(false), m_PrettyPrint(false) {}
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2037:8: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'const std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<JsonLongText::JsonToken *, 0,
      false>' for 1st argument
struct __compressed_pair_elem {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2037:8: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<JsonLongText::JsonToken *, 0, false>'
      for 1st argument
struct __compressed_pair_elem {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2050:3: note: candidate template ignored:
      substitution failure [with _Up = long, $1 = void]
  __compressed_pair_elem(_Up&& __u)
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2055:3: note: candidate constructor template not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
  __compressed_pair_elem(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args...> __args,
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2043:39: note: candidate constructor not viable:
      requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr __compressed_pair_elem() : __value_() {}
                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2141:9: error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of '__compressed_pair_elem<unsigned long *, 0>'
      : _Base1(std::forward<_Tp>(__t)), _Base2() {}
        ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:423:7: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<unsigned long *, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >::__compressed_pair<long, true>' requested here
      __end_cap_(nullptr)
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:473:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >::__vector_base' requested here
    vector() _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_default_constructible<allocator_type>::value)
    ^
../Include/JsonLongText.h:162:2: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >::vector'
      requested here
        JsonLongText() : m_IgnoreEmptyItems(true), m_RequireItemSeparator(false), m_PrettyPrint(false) {}
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2037:8: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'const std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<unsigned long *, 0, false>' for
      1st argument
struct __compressed_pair_elem {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2037:8: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<unsigned long *, 0, false>' for 1st
      argument
struct __compressed_pair_elem {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2050:3: note: candidate template ignored:
      substitution failure [with _Up = long, $1 = void]
  __compressed_pair_elem(_Up&& __u)
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2055:3: note: candidate constructor template not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
  __compressed_pair_elem(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args...> __args,
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2043:39: note: candidate constructor not viable:
      requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr __compressed_pair_elem() : __value_() {}
```

I tried to replace whole directory /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 with files from another Mac where is XCode 9.2. With these files the build of my project finishes sucessfully. It looks like libc++ in the current version of XCode is corrupted.

So, it's possible to downgrade version of XCode or to upgrade libc++?

---

EDIT:
Similar errors crop up when try to use regex. Following code (copied from cppreference):

```
// Simple regular expression matching
std::string fnames[] = {"foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.dat", "zoidberg"};
std::regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");

for (const auto &fname : fnames) {
    std::cout << fname << ": " << std::regex_match(fname, txt_regex) << '\n';
}
```

compile command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -DSTATIC_LIB -g -I . -I ../../../../openssl/iOS/include -o out/Expression.o -c Expression.cpp
```

cause:

```
In file included from Expression.cpp:113:
In file included from ./StdAfx.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2051:9: error: cannot initialize a member subobject
      of type 'std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *' with an rvalue of type 'long'
      : __value_(_VSTD::forward<_Up>(__u)){};
        ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2151:9: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *, 0, false>::__compressed_pair_elem<long, void>' requested here
      : _Base1(std::forward<_U1>(__t1)), _Base2(std::forward<_U2>(__t2)) {}
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:432:7: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> >
      >::__compressed_pair<long, const std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > &>' requested here
      __end_cap_(nullptr, __a)
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:485:11: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::sub_match<const char *>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > >::__vector_base' requested here
        : __base(__a)
          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:5355:7: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::vector<std::__1::sub_match<const char *>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > >::vector' requested here
    : __matches_(__a),
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2988:34: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::match_results<const char *, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > >::match_results' requested here
    match_results<const _CharT*> __m;
                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2978:5: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use
      -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    __lookahead(const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __exp, bool __invert, __node<_CharT>* __s, unsigned __mexp)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:4098:35: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_term<const char *>' requested here
        _ForwardIterator __temp = __parse_term(__first, __last);
                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:4074:31: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_alternative<const char *>' requested here
    _ForwardIterator __temp = __parse_alternative(__first, __last);
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:3026:19: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_ecma_exp<const char *>' requested here
        __first = __parse_ecma_exp(__first, __last);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2522:10: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse<const char *>' requested here
        {__parse(__p, __p + __traits_.length(__p));}
         ^
Expression.cpp:3356:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex' requested here
    std::regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");
               ^
In file included from Expression.cpp:113:
In file included from ./StdAfx.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2051:9: error: cannot initialize a member subobject
      of type 'std::__1::__state<char> *' with an rvalue of type 'long'
      : __value_(_VSTD::forward<_Up>(__u)){};
        ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2141:9: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::__state<char> *, 0, false>::__compressed_pair_elem<long, void>' requested here
      : _Base1(std::forward<_Tp>(__t)), _Base2() {}
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:423:7: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::__state<char> *, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__state<char> > >::__compressed_pair<long, true>'
      requested here
      __end_cap_(nullptr)
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:473:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::__state<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__state<char> > >::__vector_base' requested here
    vector() _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_default_constructible<allocator_type>::value)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:5536:21: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::vector<std::__1::__state<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__state<char> > >::vector' requested here
    vector<__state> __states;
                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2990:29: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__match_at_start_ecma<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *>
      > >' requested here
    bool __matched = __exp_.__match_at_start_ecma(
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2978:5: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use
      -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    __lookahead(const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __exp, bool __invert, __node<_CharT>* __s, unsigned __mexp)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:4098:35: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_term<const char *>' requested here
        _ForwardIterator __temp = __parse_term(__first, __last);
                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:4074:31: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_alternative<const char *>' requested here
    _ForwardIterator __temp = __parse_alternative(__first, __last);
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:3026:19: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_ecma_exp<const char *>' requested here
        __first = __parse_ecma_exp(__first, __last);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2522:10: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse<const char *>' requested here
        {__parse(__p, __p + __traits_.length(__p));}
         ^
Expression.cpp:3356:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex' requested here
    std::regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");
               ^
In file included from Expression.cpp:113:
In file included from ./StdAfx.h:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:643:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2141:9: error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of '__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *, 0>'
      : _Base1(std::forward<_Tp>(__t)), _Base2() {}
        ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:423:7: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> >
      >::__compressed_pair<long, true>' requested here
      __end_cap_(nullptr)
      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:473:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::sub_match<const char *>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > >::__vector_base' requested here
    vector() _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_default_constructible<allocator_type>::value)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:1326:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::vector<std::__1::sub_match<const char *>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> > >::vector' requested here
    __state()
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:5545:28: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__state<char>::__state' requested here
        __states.push_back(__state());
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2990:29: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__match_at_start_ecma<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::sub_match<const char *>
      > >' requested here
    bool __matched = __exp_.__match_at_start_ecma(
                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2978:5: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use
      -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    __lookahead(const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __exp, bool __invert, __node<_CharT>* __s, unsigned __mexp)
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:4098:35: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_term<const char *>' requested here
        _ForwardIterator __temp = __parse_term(__first, __last);
                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:4074:31: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_alternative<const char *>' requested here
    _ForwardIterator __temp = __parse_alternative(__first, __last);
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:3026:19: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse_ecma_exp<const char *>' requested here
        __first = __parse_ecma_exp(__first, __last);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/regex:2522:10: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::__parse<const char *>' requested here
        {__parse(__p, __p + __traits_.length(__p));}
         ^
Expression.cpp:3356:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::basic_regex<char, std::__1::regex_traits<char> >::basic_regex' requested here
    std::regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2037:8: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'const std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::sub_match<const char
      *> *, 0, false>' for 1st argument
struct __compressed_pair_elem {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2037:8: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'long' to 'std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *,
      0, false>' for 1st argument
struct __compressed_pair_elem {
       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2050:3: note: candidate template ignored:
      substitution failure [with _Up = long, $1 = void]
  __compressed_pair_elem(_Up&& __u)
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2055:3: note: candidate constructor template not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
  __compressed_pair_elem(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args...> __args,
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2043:39: note: candidate constructor not viable:
      requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr __compressed_pair_elem() : __value_() {}
```

Comment: Depending on how you are compiling you may need to allow xcode to reinstall the command line tools.

Comment: I added better example with regex, because upload whole class JsonLongText is nearly imposible.

Comment: @Richard Hodges: I've reinstalled commanline tools, but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you try with Clang instead of GCC, and add `-stdlib=libc++` to your build command line?

Comment: `libstdc++` is the GNU C++ standard library for C++98, which does not have C++11 support.  Are you sure you don't want to use `libc++`, which is the LLVM C++ standard library with C++11/14/17 support?

Comment: @Eljay: yeah, your're right. I ment libc++. I forgot that LLVM defaulty uses libc++.

Comment: @Nicolas Tisserand: I'm currently using Clang and libc++. g++ is mapped to Clang on my Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can now reproduce your exact `regex` error, verbatim, on my machine.

The trick is to redefine `nullptr` to `0u` as a preprocessor symbol, before including the `vector` standard library header (which `regex` depends on):

```
#define nullptr 0l

#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::string fnames[] = {"foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.dat", "zoidberg"};
    std::regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");

    for (const auto &fname : fnames)
        std::cout << fname << ": " << std::regex_match(fname, txt_regex) << '\n';
}
```

In light of the above, I now think your issue is a case of header preprocessor namespace pollution: some header, somewhere in the inclusion chain of your failing translation unit, likely defines a `nullptr` macro this way, which causes errors with the implementation of the standard library shipped with Xcode 9.3, but (I speculate) not with other implementations, for some reason.

I would suggest inspecting the preprocessor output using `g++ -E`, and check on what becomes of the offending code at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:432`, where I believe the errors are being initially triggered.

Alternatively, you can try always including `vector` first in your translation units. I suspect this would allow you to dodge the issue, while you keep looking for the root cause.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. My former colleague really defined `nullptr` 8 years ago because of MSVC2010. Unfortunately he guarded it only by `#if (_MSC_VER < 1600)`. He forgot to check `_WIN32`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem,xcode version 12.4,carefully check my code and find that there are a define: # define nullptr (NULL).When removing this code, the build succeeds again.